# How to use Nginx alias to load PHP from other directory?

Tags: nginx

I want to make a sub directory my on web server, `system` that serves a backend from another folder for people, but I am having some difficulty.

The server configuration should translate `system` as `index.php` of the `/srv/www/xxx/backend/web`, essentially `system` should alias to the index of another directory.

I have a configuration like:

```
location /system {
    alias /srv/www/xxx/backend/web;
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?r=$1;
    return 200 $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;

        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location / {
    rewrite /(.*) /index.php?r=$1;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    try_files $uri =404;

    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I have tried numerous iterations (including using `root`), however even though I can get:

```
return 200 $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

to give me:

```
/srv/www/xxx/backend/web/index.php
```

and I have vi'ed into this file to make sure it works when I take out the return wget gives me a 404. I am sure I am missing something really simple.

Can someone help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: @XavierLucas oops so I did, bad copy

Comment: Oh ok. What do you have in error logs ?

Comment: @XavierLucas nout, it just has "process started" and that's it

Comment: You could try to strace the processes to see what happens : `strace -f -p $(pgrep -f "nginx: master") | egrep -i "open|stat"`.

Comment: @XavierLucas I do belive I know what is going on, it is not hitting into the PHP block within the location despite the print out. as such it leaves the location and loses the printout vars making it some path that cannot be found

Comment: Oh yeah as it is nested, it falls back in the last location block of your configuration because the URI doens't start with `/system`.

Comment: @XavierLucas indeed, is there a way around this?

Comment: You can simply add the prefix `/system` and rewrite in the php location block to remove it : `rewrite ^(.*) /system/index.php?r=$1;` in the /system root location then `rewrite ^/system/(.*)$ /$1;` in the nested php location.

Comment: @XavierLucas the problem is that images etc will try and load from system in that case won't they?

Comment: Yeah they will, use try_files in that case so they are resolved before falling back in the nested location : `try_files $uri /system/index.php?r=$1;`. But you won't be able to use alias anymore (yeah it's a boring bug). So it must be handled in the rewrite. I can post an answer with the final setup if you want.

Comment: @XavierLucas for some reason adding the rewrite to that nested php block seems to make it revert back to trying to pull from the server block, so I removed that line and it tries to laod from system folder now, which is wrong and of course a 404

Comment: Add the break flag at the end of the rewrite directive so it doesn't leave the location where the directive is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As location php is nested the `/index.php` URI is not resolved here but in the last block of your configuration. Due to a [long standing bug](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) in nginx alias doesn't work with try_files so you need to use the [root/rewrite couple instead](https://serverfault.com/questions/642579/how-can-i-get-around-using-alias-in-nginx/642584). So you can fix this with :

```
location /system {

    root /srv/www/xxx/backend/web;
    rewrite ^/system/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    try_files $uri /system/index.php?r=$uri;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        rewrite ^/system/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;

        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location / {
    rewrite /(.*) /index.php?r=$1;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    try_files $uri =404;

    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Thanks after much trial and error I was finally able to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

To complete the accepted answer, I add some parts to get static files working:

```
location ~ ^/system(.*) {
    root /srv/www/xxx/backend/web;
    rewrite ^/system/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    try_files $uri /system/index.php?r=$1&$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        rewrite ^/system/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ (.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|mp4|ogg|woff|ttf))$ {
        rewrite ^/system/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

The last location solves the static files problem whereby files would not load from this place.